# how to prevent process on old files in `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter `?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

Thanks for attention
i used `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter` in spring integration, i want to retreive files from ftp server and process on it, and save backup in local directory , but when application in starting state `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter` create message from local old files in backup location and try send to  channel my code as bellow  :

```
 <bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
          class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />

     <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sam-inbound-channel-adapter"
                                         channel="sam-ready-to-process-inbound"
                                         session-factory="sam-ftp-Session"
                                         auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                         delete-remote-files="true"
                                         auto-startup="true"
                                         filename-pattern="*.bmp"
                                         remote-directory="/in/"
                                         remote-file-separator="/"
                                         local-filter="acceptOnceFilter"
                                         preserve-timestamp="true"
                                         local-filename-generator-expression="@fileName.name('sam',#this)"
                                         temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                         local-directory="./backup/sam/in//">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
        </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [see the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound). You can use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` in `local-filter`, together with a `MetadataStore` of your choice, to prevent files from being reprocessed after a restart.

However, it's generally better to delete/rename the file after processing; otherwise performance will degrade over time as the number of files in the local directory that have to be scanned is increased.

Since you are deleting the remote file, you don't need it, but (for completeness) there is also a `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` (in `filter`) to prevent re-fetching files after a restart (needed when `delete-remote-files` is false).

Comment: thanks for response @Gary, yes you are right, i used a `tmp` directory and moved the files to another for processing and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Gary for help me in design my project, for solving the problem i used a `int-file:outbound-gateway` for moving the file to another directory as bellow :

```
<int:channel id="ready-to-process-inbound"/>
<int:channel id="ready-to-process-inbound-tmp-mover"/>

  <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="inbound-channel-adapter"
                                     channel="ready-to-process-inbound-tmp-mover"
                                     session-factory="ftp-Session"
                                     auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                     delete-remote-files="true"
                                     auto-startup="true"
                                     filename-pattern="*.bmp"
                                     remote-directory="/in/"
                                     remote-file-separator="/"
                                     preserve-timestamp="true"
                                     local-filename-generator-expression="@fileNameGenerator.by('prefix',#this)"
                                     temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                     local-directory="./backup//tmp//">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

 <int-file:outbound-gateway id="file-outbound-gateway-tmp-mover"
                               request-channel="ready-to-process-inbound-tmp-mover"
                               reply-channel="ready-to-process-inbound"
                               directory="./backup//in//"
                               mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true"/>
```